# Recycling when using `crossprod` in R?

Tags: r, function

While my function works fine, I'm wondering how to avoid the warning below when running my simple function?

> Warning message: In numer/denom :   Recycling array of length 1 in
>   vector-array arithmetic is deprecated.   Use c() or as.vector()
>   instead.

```
qq <- function(f, df1, df2, N){
       denom <- crossprod(df1, f) + df2 + 1  # I suspect warning is from here?
       numer <-  (df1 * (f - 1))
       return(numer / denom)
}

# Example of use:
qq(f = c(84.11, 4.05, 8.38), df1 = c(3, 1, 3), df2 = 24, N = 32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning occurs at the `return` function.

Try

```
return(numer / as.numeric(denom))
```

The reason is `denom` is a matrix, and  `number` is an atomic vector. 
I also thought there wouldn't be a warning, but it seems the operation you did has been depreciated.